# Is it possible to reset a modified Airbag Control Unit to factory default?

Tags: bmw, electronic-control-module, supplemental-restraint-system, 320d

I discovered my BMW E46 320d has been in a small crash and the airbag was deployed. The previous owner didn't fix it correctly and reused the airbag and modified the Airbag Control Unit (probably just software). BMW can't fix it because of their modified Control Units policy.

My question is: can I reset the Airbag Control Unit back to its default settings? Doing this is probably half way there since I discovered this because of the Takata Airbag recall, which ended up with BMW installing a new airbag for free.

Comment: Probably best to get a new unit... Which is probably why BMW have that policy...